# how to replace a time variable in a string to epoch

Tags: python-3.x

I'm playing around with getting a string with date format and values transformed to influxdb ready import.
Therefore I'm trying to transform the datetime to epoch timestamp in python.

What I've so far.

```
#Import of some modules
import re
from datetime import date
import time, os

#example text which I'll retrieve daily
txt = "daily power [{'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.483}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.269}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.611}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 5, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.61}]"

#Regex patterns
date_regex = r'\d+,\s\d+,\s\d+'
consump_regex = r'\w+\':\s\d+.\d+'
regex_plug = r'\w+\(\d+\,\s\d+\,\s\d+\,\s\d+\,\s\d+\)\,\s\'\w+\'\:\s\d+\.\d+'

x= re.findall(regex_plug, txt)
nl = ("\n".join(x))
condition1 = str(nl).replace(",", "-")
condition2 = condition1.replace(" ", "",)
condition3 = condition2.replace("':", "': ")
condition4 = condition3.replace("(", "': ")
condition5 = condition4.replace(")-", " ")
condition6 = condition5.replace("d", "'d")
print(condition6)
```

results in:

```
'datetime': 2020-12-1-0-0 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.483
'datetime': 2020-12-2-0-0 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.269
'datetime': 2020-11-4-0-0 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.611
'datetime': 2020-11-5-0-0 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.61
```

The last step is to transform the time to epoch timestamp, but I don't get this working.

I found already some threads describing how to replace date to epoch. with

```
date_time = '2020-12-1-0-0' #should be txt
pattern = '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M'
epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern)))
print(epoch)
```

But how can I process this over my condition6 string, to make the output:

```
'datetime': 1606780800 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.483
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `eval`:

```
import datetime

txt = "daily power [{'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.483}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.269}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.611}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 5, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.61}]"
daily_power = eval(txt.strip().strip("daily power"))
# Now just convert the datetimes to timestamps:
for d in daily_power:
    d['date'] = d['date'].timestamp()
print(daily_power) # Yields wanted result.
```

An approach without using `eval` (due to safety etc):

```
from ast import literal_eval as leval

date_cons = re.findall(r'{[^\{\}]+}', txt)
for idx, dc in enumerate(date_cons):
    dtnums = re.search(r'\((?:\d+,?\s*){5}\)', dc).group()
    ts = datetime.datetime(*leval(dtnums)).timestamp()
    date_cons[idx] = leval(re.sub('datetime\.datetime\(.+\)', str(ts), dc))

print(date_cons) # Yields wanted result.
```

If you dont even want to use `literal_eval` (which is safe) you can just use more regex.

Comment: Welp, that is an oneliner I should have known earlier. Will make the import as well easier to influx.

However I don't get the datetime.datetime command correctly. I can't find the correct way to change it to epoch.

Should be something like:
epoch = datetime.datetime().timestamp() ?

Comment: @WimOrigin yes exactly, if you're using python 3.3+ [`datetime.datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) should do the trick.

Comment: I get the following message:

TypeError: function missing required argument 'year' (pos 1)

Comment: @WimOrigin it works with the example `txt` string you provided. It looks like you tried parsing a `datetime.datetime` instance that doesn't provide the [required arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). For example `datetime.datetime()`.

Comment: I probably do something stupid.
I test with the same example in https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_regex.

Same txt, which I stripped to make it an actual list.
I possibly am not correctly entering the dict with datetime objects.
What did you do to get the datetime.datetime.timestamp() working on my original txt example ?

Comment: can you please post your working example?

Comment: @WimOrigin Edited. I also added an approach without `eval`. Both work and provide the wanted result.

Comment: ...............................txt = "daily power [{'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0), 'total_consumption_kwh': 0.483},
daily_power = eval(txt.strip().strip("daily power"))
# Now just convert the datetimes to timestamps:
for d in daily_power:
    d['date'] = d['date'].timestamp()
print(daily_power) # Yields wanted result.                                                                                                                                                  I needed to add a line that tells timestamp to add (CEST, +0200). Thank you very much